# Customizing subtitles with AVPlayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, avplayer

I was able to display a subtitle track with `AVPlayer` on iOS 6, but I am not able to customize it. It just shows the same style (a small font size, in white).

Here's how I select the subtitle:

```
AVMediaSelectionGroup *subtitle = [asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic: AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];
[self.videoPlayer.currentItem selectMediaOption:subtitle.options[0] inMediaSelectionGroup: subtitle];
```

And how I'm trying to customize the subtitle:

```
AVTextStyleRule *rule = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc] initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{
                         (id)kCMTextMarkupAttribute_ForegroundColorARGB : @[ @1, @1, @0, @0 ],
                         (id) kCMTextMarkupAttribute_ItalicStyle : @(YES)}];

self.videoPlayer.currentItem.textStyleRules = @[rule];
```

No matter if I put this snippet before or after selecting the subtitle, the result is the same.

The `AVPlayer` is created with a local (file) URL (a mp4 file).

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: this isn't from experience, but could you try creating two separate rules, setting one attribute per rule, and then adding both rules in the array of rules to establish?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked this question on Apple Developer Forums and I got [an answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/868318#868318) from an Apple employee:

> The `textStyleRules` property only applies to WebVTT content.  Your local file is probably carrying subtitles in TX3G format.
>
> You're right that the documentation doesn't mention this limitation, so you should file a bug so we can get our documentation updated.

So, I'll open a radar to ask that they update the docs and I'll post its number here if someone wants to dupe it.

**EDIT**:

I created [rdar://14923673](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5775305083977728) to ask Apple to update the docs about this current limitation. I also created [rdar://14923755](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5763210456072192) to ask them to provide support to subtitles in TX3G format.

Please dupe them if you're affected by this issue.

Comment: I want to duplicate! Let's put some pressure on them. :)

Comment: I haven't been able to do this yet. I'll try to do it later today. I intend to open 2 radars: one about docs and another one about providing this feature.

Comment: It seems to be contradicting that they support it for web resources and not for local ones, given that they are able to visualize it anyway. I'd think they could use the same code for adding the text.

Comment: I agree. That's why I'll open two radars: one to ask them to make clear on the docs that this method only supports web resources, and another one to make it compatible with local ones.

Comment: "so we can get our documentation updated", coming from Apple? Hahaha, yea okay..

Answer (score 7):

I found workaround to modify text foreground color and background correctly.
Just separate styles to multiple AVTextStyleRule.

```
func initSubtitleStyle() {
    let textStyle:AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_CharacterBackgroundColorARGB as String: [0.2,0.3,0.0,0.3]
        ])!


    let textStyle1:AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_ForegroundColorARGB as String: [0.2,0.8,0.4,0.0]
        ])!

    let textStyle2:AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_BaseFontSizePercentageRelativeToVideoHeight as String: 20,
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_CharacterEdgeStyle as String: kCMTextMarkupCharacterEdgeStyle_None
        ])!

    player.currentItem?.textStyleRules = [textStyle, textStyle1, textStyle2]
}
```

please do not ask me why, that solution come from try and error XD

Comment: wow, thanks man, i wasted all day because this, by casuality do you know if it's possible to present the subtitles of avplayer into another view? not in a layer, thanks again

Comment: you know how can i remove black background?