# Customizing subtitles with AVPlayer objective c

Tags: objective-c, avplayer, subtitle

I was able to display a subtitle track with AVPlayer on iOS 10, but I am not able to customize it.

here's How I'm trying to customize the subtitle:

```
    AVMediaSelectionGroup* subtitle = [asset mediaSelectionGroupForMediaCharacteristic:AVMediaCharacteristicLegible];
[player.currentItem selectMediaOption:subtitle.options[0] inMediaSelectionGroup:subtitle];

AVTextStyleRule* rule = [[AVTextStyleRule alloc]initWithTextMarkupAttributes:@{

                                                                               (id)kCMTextFormatDescriptionStyle_FontSize : @40, (id)kCMTextFormatDescriptionStyle_Font : [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Italic" size:10]
                                                                              }];

player.currentItem.textStyleRules = @[rule];
```

I can't change color or font of subtitle .

The `AVPlayer` is created with URL

Comment: I believe, that it the same problem with subtitles format: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18260397/485174 and that customatization applicable only to WebVTT content.

Comment: @belous I can change size of subtitle but can't change color or font .

Comment: @P.Tb you should implant this settings before playing video, if you set this rules after playing that's not effect on your subtitle.