# problems with AVPlayer subtitles enhancement with AVTextStyleRule's

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I'm iOS software developer, new to AVPlayer. I'm trying to customise subtitles provided to the player. Unfortunately documentation is very poor and i didn't find any proper tutorial anywhere. Some of my **kCMTextMarkupAttribute** works, some of them don't:

```
    //1
    let textStyleCharacterBackgroundColor: AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_CharacterBackgroundColorARGB as String: [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    ])!
    
    //2
    let textStyleSize: AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_RelativeFontSize as String: relativeFontSize
    ])!

    //3
    let textBackgroundColor: AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_BackgroundColorARGB as String: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ,0.0]
    ])!
    
    //4
    let textFont: AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_FontFamilyName  as String: "Montserrat"
    ])!

    //5
    let textCharacterEdgeStyle: AVTextStyleRule = AVTextStyleRule(textMarkupAttributes: [
        kCMTextMarkupAttribute_CharacterEdgeStyle as String: kCMTextMarkupCharacterEdgeStyle_DropShadow
    ])!

    currentItem?.textStyleRules = [textStyleCharacterBackgroundColor, textStyleSize, textBackgroundColor, textFont, textCharacterEdgeStyle]
```

According to my tests: //2, //4 works fine. I have a few question to the other ones. Please, help me if you can :)

**//3  kCMTextMarkupAttribute_BackgroundColorARGB**
I would like to have a clear background around text, but unfortunately it doesn't work and i still receive black background with alpha.
If i try to add for example a red background it does work, so i assume that there is kind of a "default background" and by making *kCMTextMarkupAttribute_BackgroundColorARGB as String: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ,0.0]* i just add "clean background" additionally.
When i use *kCMTextMarkupAttribute_BackgroundColorARGB as String: [0.5, 0.5, 0.0 ,0.0]* i receive red background. Do you know what should i do to receive clean background instead of black one with alpha? If there is a default background, can i turn it off?

**//1 kCMTextMarkupAttribute_CharacterBackgroundColorARGB**

**//5 kCMTextMarkupAttribute_CharacterEdgeStyle**

No matter what values i provide for //1 and //5 nothing happen.

What is a CharacterBackground? I try to use them to receive black edge around letters and black shadow around them.

Generally i need:

1. clear background in subtitles frame
2. black edge around letters
3. black shadow around letters

Could you help me somehow?

Comment: Isn't it depends on the preferences you have for Subtitles & Captioning in settings?

Comment: Couls you explain sth more, i.m new to AvPlayer, it there any other place where i can customise subtitles settings?

Comment: Check this out if it works in your case: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44692804/6576315

Comment: As you Can see, i've already seen this questian and already split styles to multiple AVTextStyleRule

Comment: Then create a new style and turn on video override for background color in Subtitle and Captioning settings.

Comment: Tahnk you, it does work, it is not a saolution for me, but at least i understand how it works.

Comment: @JanekPodwysocki do you found answer for your question? if yes please write your answer because i need this, thanks =)